# C# using odbcDataReader: Change decimal seperator from "." to "," in Decimal value

Tags: c#, database-connection, decimalformat

When I try to assign a value from the odbcDataReader to a 'Decimal' variable it removes the decimal seperator ",". The value itself is stored as a decimal in the database I'm retrieving data from. I have tried to use the CultureInfo like this:

```
   CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
   myCI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
   OdbcDataReader Reader = null;
   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("...");
   cmd.Connection = cn;
   Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (Reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        *(decimal variable)* p = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader["Decimal Value"], myCI);
                    }
                }
```

I'm located in the EU if that makes sense, our default decimal seperator is "," but I have to connect to another DB that uses "." as decimal seperator so I cannot change the default decimal settings to ",", I only need to have THIS value use "," as a decimal seperator. I feel like my problem is in the CultureInfo but cannot find a clear solution.

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: What means it removes it? What is a sample decimal number? What it's in your database and what it is C#? In general there is no format. It seems you confuse a string with decimal. You can display a decimal in any format you like.

Comment: Your variable `p` has no decimal separator, and neither does any `decimal`. The only time you need a separator is when you present the value in a front end. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Can you tell me: what does `Reader["Decimal Value"].GetType().Name` returns? basically: what is the underlying value here? A `decimal` *has no concept of formatting* - it is just a pure number. BTW - it is usually a very bad idea to *change* the parts of a format-info - why not fetch a specific culture info that matches the pattern you expect?

Comment: the Database value is '0,400', if I use my code the variable 'p' is assigned the value '4'. What do you mean with 'fetch a specific culture info that matches the pattern you expect' ?

Comment: @MarcGravell The "Reader["Decimal Value"].GetType().Name" returns "Decimal"

Comment: @Witloofdc then it is already a decimal - there is nothing to parse, and no amount of culture-info will make any difference. The `Convert.ToDecimal` here will basically be saying "but... it is already a decimal - here, have it back!" i.e. `if(val is decimal) return (decimal)val;`

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for the information. I have looked further and solved it by making my variable a 'Double' and using the code: `p = Reader.GetDouble(Reader.GetOrdinal("Value"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Decimal variable was a wrong choice of me, I have changed it to a double and the code `p = Reader.GetDouble(Reader.GetOrdinal("Value"));` works as I expected it to do.

Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it;

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
*(decimal variable)* p = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader["Decimal Value"], myCI);
}
```

to

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
    decimal p = 0;

    decimal.TryParse(Reader["ColumnName"].ToString().Replace('.',','), out p);
}
```

OR

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
    double p = double.Parse(Reader["ColumnName"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```